# How do I draw multiple rectangles in Android Studio and move them (with touch) without individually programming each rectangle

Tags: java, android

I'm currently trying to write an app that allows you to move a (red) rectangle from the bottom left corner to any position you want. After you release the first rectangle, you should be able to move another one from the bottom left corner to anywhere you want, as often as you want. With my following code you can only have a maximum of 3 movable rectangles, as I manually create individual variables for each new rectangle. Is there a way to do that automatically as soon as more variables are needed so you can have as many rectangles as you wish?

Yes I already searched for solutions to this problem but it is very specific so I did not find anything I was able to make use of.
I am a beginner, so my code is kind of chaotic. Sorry for that.

Here my code (the important one should be the DrawView.java)

DrawView.java:

```
public class DrawView extends View {
    public static float xpos = -1;
    public static float ypos = -1;
    public static float xpos1 = -1;
    public static float ypos1 = -1;
    public static float xpos2 = -1;
    public static float ypos2 = -1;
    public static float xpos3 = -1;
    public static float ypos3 = -1;
    public int clicked = 0;
    public int uses = 0;
    Paint paint = new Paint();

    DisplayMetrics metrics = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    public int width = metrics.widthPixels;
    public int height = metrics.heightPixels;

    public DrawView(Context c) {
        super(c);
        setFocusable(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (xpos == -1 && ypos == -1) {
            xpos = 70;
            ypos = height - 90;
            xpos1 = xpos;
            ypos1 = ypos;
            xpos2 = xpos;
            ypos2 = ypos;
            xpos3 = xpos;
            ypos3 = ypos;
        }

        paint.setStrokeWidth(0);
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        canvas.drawRect(50, 50, 70+(uses*20), 70+(clicked*20), paint); //for testing
        paint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        canvas.drawRect(0, height-150, 800, height, paint);
        paint.setColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        canvas.drawRect(0, height-160, 800, height-150, paint);
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        canvas.drawRect(xpos-50, ypos-50, xpos+50, ypos+50, paint);

        if (uses >= 0) {
            canvas.drawRect(xpos1 - 50, ypos1 - 50, xpos1 + 50, ypos1 + 50, paint);
        }

        if (uses >= 1) {
            canvas.drawRect(xpos2-50, ypos2-50, xpos2+50, ypos2+50, paint);
        }

        if (uses >= 2) {
            canvas.drawRect(xpos3-50, ypos3-50, xpos3+50, ypos3+50, paint);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();

        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN && clicked == 0) {
            float cx = event.getX();
            float cy = event.getY();
            if (cx >= (xpos1 - 50) && cx <= (xpos1 + 50) && cy >= (ypos1 - 50) && cy <= (ypos1 + 50) && uses >= 0) {
                clicked = 1;
            }
            if (cx >= (xpos2 - 50) && cx <= (xpos2 + 50) && cy >= (ypos2 - 50) && cy <= (ypos2 + 50) && uses >= 1) {
                clicked = 2;
            }
            if (cx >= (xpos3 - 50) && cx <= (xpos3 + 50) && cy >= (ypos3 - 50) && cy <= (ypos3 + 50) && uses >= 2) {
                clicked = 3;
            }
        }

        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE && clicked == 1) {
            float dx = event.getX() - xpos1;
            float dy = event.getY() - ypos1;
            xpos1 += dx;
            ypos1 += dy;
        }
        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && uses == 0 && clicked == 1) {
            uses += 1;
            clicked = 0;
        }
        else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && clicked == 1) {
            clicked = 0;
        }

        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE && clicked == 2) {
            float dx = event.getX() - xpos2;
            float dy = event.getY() - ypos2;
            xpos2 += dx;
            ypos2 += dy;
        }
        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && uses == 1 && clicked == 2) {
            uses += 1;
            clicked = 0;
        }
        else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && clicked == 2) {
            clicked = 0;
        }

        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE && clicked == 3) {
            float dx = event.getX() - xpos3;
            float dy = event.getY() - ypos3;
            xpos3 += dx;
            ypos3 += dy;
        }
        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && uses == 2 && clicked == 3) {
            uses += 1;
            clicked = 0;
        }
        else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && clicked == 3) {
            clicked = 0;
        }

        if (xpos1 < 50) {
            xpos1 = 50;
        }
        if (xpos1 > width-50) {
            xpos1 = width-50;
        }
        if (ypos1 < 50) {
            ypos1 = 50;
        }
        if (ypos1 > height-75) {
            ypos1 = height-75;
        }

        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    DrawView drawView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        drawView = new DrawView(this);
        drawView.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        setContentView(drawView);

    }
}
```

activity_main.xml (did not change anything here):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="wuerthedv.rechteckverschieben2.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I would suggest having a look at the [Rect Class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html) and the Canvas Method `void drawRect(Rect r, Paint paint)` [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html). You can create an Instance of the Rect Class and draw that, instead of a Rect from Coordinates. If you want to easily manage the Rect Instances, you could just have an Array of Rect.

Comment: I'll just try that thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put your variables into arrays and form loops when you want to process them. So instead of:

```
public static float xpos1 = -1;
public static float ypos1 = -1;
public static float xpos2 = -1;
public static float ypos2 = -1;
public static float xpos3 = -1;
public static float ypos3 = -1;
```

You can create an array of points:

```
ArrayList<Point> arr_pos = new ArrayList<>();
arr_pos.add(new Point(-1,-1));
arr_pos.add(new Point(-1,-1));
arr_pos.add(new Point(-1,-1));
```

You can also initialise xpos, ypos as a Point:

```
Point pos = new Point(-1,-1)
```

Then in your onDraw method, you can loop through the array:

```
if (pos.x == -1 && pos.y == -1) {
        pos.x = 70;
        pos.y = height - 90;
        for (int i=0; i<arr_pos.size(); i++){
            arr_pos.add(i, new Point(pox.x, pos.y);
        }
}
```

I will leave you to work the rest out...!

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for, but now I have another problem: with a float from the ArrayList (I use two ArrayLists containing Floats instead of Points because I do not know how to use Points for drawing rectangles) as coordinate the rectangles do not move when changing the float. I did not have that problem using simple floats. Is there a solution to it?

Comment: See the comment from @FatalMerlin - you can use a Rect struct in your ArrayList if that is more suitable: ArrayList<Rect> arr_rect = new ArrayList<>(); arr_rect.add(new Rect(left, top, right, bottom)); ... Also note that Point and Rect both use integers, so maybe you should use the float equivalents which are [PointF](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PointF.html) and [RectF](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/RectF.html)